# Why are deep links not working after authentication?

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

After authenticating, the user is always sent to the root url of the application, even though they initially requested a deep link.

I've read that there is a concept of RelayState, however I'm not sure if that is something I need to explicitly look for as a property somewhere and then redirect, or something that should be functioning automatically if I have things setup correctly.

I have tried [tacking on a url to the signOn url](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/250#issuecomment-133282718) but that didn't seem to have any affect.  This is just when I manually enter a url in the browser, though, so I assume that isn't an "SP initiated login"

When I need to authenticate I am redirecting to a deep link like so (hard coded just while trying to debug)

```
string deepLink = "?returnUrl=http://localhost:35246" + app.Context.Request.FilePath;
string logInPage = "~/Saml2/SignIn" + deepLink;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(logInPage);
```

The logging output shows this.. should SignInUrl show something different?

```
SUSTAINSYS [VERBOSE] Expanded Saml2Url
  AssertionConsumerServiceUrl: http://localhost:35245/Saml2/Acs
  SignInUrl: http://localhost:35245/Saml2/SignIn
  LogoutUrl: http://localhost:35245/Saml2/Logout
  ApplicationUrl: http://localhost:35245/
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needs to be

```
?ReturnUrl=
```

rather than

```
?returnUrl=
```